# PHP: Find spreadsheet (e.g. Excel / LibreOffice Calc) column number from column title

Tags: php

I need to write a PHP function to get a spreadsheet column number from its column name (e.g. 'A' = 1, 'B' = 2, 'Z' = 26, 'AA' = 27, 'BE' = 57, 'CW' = 101, 'ZZ' = 702, 'CDA' = 2133, ...)

```
function get_col_number_from_name($col_name)
{
    // do something to determine $col_number from $col_name...

    return $col_number;
}
```

e.g. `get_col_number_from_name('BE')` must return 57

Unfortunately I cannot manage to write a suitable algorithm.
Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code below,

```
function get_col_number_from_name($col_name)
{
    $l = strlen($col_name);
    $col_number = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $col_number = $col_number * 26 + ord($col_name[$i]) - 0x40;
    }

    return $col_number;
}
```